# How to fix moduleNOtFoundError in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

`process = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'Analysis.py', '1'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`

In my script I'm trying to run the line of code above, to run Analysis script, but I get modulenotfounderror: no module named 'requests'
it is not limited to request module since attempting to run scripts this way finds first import statement and uses it for error. All scripts are in the same directory, and I'm using pycharm to run all of them.

I tried running from cmd and pycharm console, as well as reinstall all imports, import them into the script thats supposed to run other scripts, verify that they have been installed in a folder that is the part of sys.path
I have tried it on python 3.1 and 3.7 but it makes no difference

The scripts run independently without a problem but I need to have them started from a script that uses ui.
for UI I used both tkinter and customtkinter with current code looking like this:

```
import customtkinter
import subprocess


def run_script_tld():
    process = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'TLD.py'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

    output, error = process.communicate()

    output = output.decode('utf-8')

def button_function():
    run_analisis()

button = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=app, text="CTkButton", command=button_function)
button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=customtkinter.CENTER)

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: PyCharm uses virtual environments for its scripts, so modules available for that venv aren't necessarily available to the global Python installation. Most importantly though, is there any reason why you won't just use `import Analysis` and run the script in the same process?

Comment: Analysis script works by running once then restarting with new parameters its like recursion but for the whole file

Comment: @LukeG then it could probably use a rewrite of its own.

Comment: Almost certnaily but Im having problem with it, it needs to go through a list of links and send request to all of them but if I try to loop it, use recursion or threading all request return as maxtries exceeded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "python" executable program may be different when you run independently from the command line and when you run it in the UI script. Check the default path for Python, or you can use the absolute path in Popen.

Comment: Using absolute path fixed it thank you